# What does NP and NO means in datasheets?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I will be using a DC-DC Converter from Cincon: [EC4BW11](https://www.mouser.ph/datasheet/2/75/EC4BW-V13-542250.pdf)
I do not understand what NP and NO means on the pinouts. I am assuming that the input voltage will be connected on pins 1 and 2 (+Input, -Input) and the output voltage on pins 3 and 5 (+Output, -Output) since this is and ISOLATED DC-DC Converter which would mean they don't have a common ground?

Would the pin 4 (Common/NP) mean that this is the common for dual output, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this isn't a dual function pin...it's either common (and although it's not stated, it seems clear it's the common (ground) for dual output devices) or it's not there.  NP stands for No Pin...there's no "NO" abbreviation, it's just saying in the comment that NP stands for NO PIN.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - I would assume that pin 4 is the common for the dual output versions.  The note below the pinout table also states that that pin is missing on the single output versions.